# convert css file into inline styles in HTML using npm package

Tags: javascript, html, css, npm

I have HTML file with external css file, like to inline the styles in external style sheet into one inline `<style>` tag at the top of the head . Thanks in advance for any help

**Note**: Do not want to use style attribute applied to each element, want to have one style tag at the top

Before Converting

```css
p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>HTML Template</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myscript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Welcome to Template!!</p>
</body>

</html>
```

After Converting

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>HTML Template</title>
  <!-- START: Replaced inline tag from external css file mystyle.css as above-->
  <style>
    .p {
      color: red
    }
  </style>
  <!-- END: Replaced inline tag from external css file mystyle.css as above-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myscript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Welcome to Template!!</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start by make your html file accessible from web browser
if you use php, you can make it accessible by run following command `php -S 127.0.0.1:4000` , make sure you can access it by open localhost:4000 on your web browser, there are another way how to accessible from another languages, but it's out of the scope of this question

the second step is install `inliner` npm package `npm install -g inliner`

and execute `inliner http://localhost:4000 > output.html`

open `output.html` to see the result

execute `inliner -i http://localhost:4000 > output.html` if you don't want to convert the image to be base64 encoded

Comment: `inliner` is deprecated, so not recommeded